# Regex - Select the inverse

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble selecting the opposite of what i previously selected

String:

```
<!-- Button --><div><button></div><!-- Input --><input type="text">
```

I managed to select the comments by using:

```
/<!--[\s\w]*-->/
```

Now I want to select everything but the comments. Desired output

```
<div><button></div> and <input type="text">
```

My question is what would the Regex search string be in order to select the previously mentioned output ?

Comment: Will matching and replacing your comments with empty string work?

Comment: Use a parser instead!

Comment: Yes, kind of but, I am looking for a regex search string

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi yes

Comment: What does everything but the comments mean? Presuming this is a HTML page you want the entire HTML excluding the comments? This isn't going to be practical using regex, not to mention you really shouldn't be trying to [parse HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/542251)

Comment: Read up on positive/negative lookaheads/lookbehinds, and then decide against doing what you want to do. You shouldn't be parsing HTML with Regex, unless _maybe_ if it's just locally in an IDE and not using JavaScript (or any other languages).

Comment: I updated the question maybe it is a little clearer now.. @mickmackusa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had previously had problems with Regex only selecting the first instance but I found out I was missing the global tag `/.../g`

The answer to getting the inverse is `/<[^!]*?>.*?>/g`

```js
var s = '<!-- Button --><div><button></div><!-- Input --><input type="text">'
console.log(s.match(/<[^!]*?>/g))
```

Reference: 
https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

Comment: This does not provide the output that you stated in your question.  Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/75rLaeoj/  This answer individually matches each html tag.  Either the question is wrong or this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Steinar you need to clarify what you wanted out of this question/answer. It doesn't make sense right now as your apparent solution doesn't solve your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the js equivalent of php's preg_split with PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY is like this:

```
yourstring.split(/<!--[\s\w]*-->/g).filter(n => n)
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75rLaeoj/

Using a dom parser may be a little more complicated because you want to group one or more tags together.

Comment: @Steinar does this work properly for your project data? If not please provide a realistic sample that breaks it so that I can make an adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get the inverse is to replace the regex selection:

```js
let html = '<!-- Button --><div><button></div><!-- Input --><input type="text">'

let noComments = html.replace(/<!--[\s\w]*-->/g,"") 

console.log(noComments) //<div><button></div><input type="text">
```

Comment: This upvoted answer is not what the OP wants.  I wish voters would be more discerning.

Comment: This answer returns a string, the OP wants an array of qualifying strings.

Comment: @mickmackusa Looks like the output from OP's own answer is pretty much the same as mine. Maybe it's time to remove your downvote from my answer?

Comment: It appears you don't know the difference between a string and an array, I've been very clear about why your answer is wrong.

Comment: @mickmackusa So the OP's also wrong I suppose. I read his tone in "Yes, kind of but," and interpreted it as such. You interpreted it as an array and nothing else, which is kinda unnecessarily literal imho. But hey I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: Then I commend you for your restraint.  Questions here need to be clear and all answers should provide the exact desired output.  The OP stated that he/she wants `this` and `that`.  These two items are not expressed as a single string, they are expressed as two separate strings or else the desired output would have been written `thisthat`.  It is important to precisely answer questions here because future researchers come here to learn.

Comment: I guess I felt that returning html code stripped of comments would make a lot more sense to the OP than returning random html fragments that had arbitrarily been separated by comments. But hey that's me.

Comment: I don't know how you can possibly make that judgement.   I don't have a crystal ball at my house.